# Error when applying Pytorch pre-trained weights' transform on Huggingface dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to train/fine-tune the MobileNetV3 model on the CIFAR100 dataset. I'm using Pytorch and Huggingface to simplify things like training loop which I'm not used to having to do manually coming from Tensorflow/Keras.

However, I get an error when trying to apply the pre-trained weights' transform (preprocessing) to the dataset with the `.with_transform()` method. I wanted to visualize the preprocessing partly to see that it actually works.

If I apply the preprocessing manually on an image it works, but if I used the with_transform method, I get an error.

Minimum reproducible example:

```py
import torch
from torchvision.models import MobileNet_V3_Small_Weights
from datasets import load_dataset
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

weights = MobileNet_V3_Small_Weights.DEFAULT
preprocess = weights.transforms()

raw_data = load_dataset("cifar100")
data = raw_data.with_transform(preprocess)

raw_img = raw_data["train"][0]["img"]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)

axes[0].imshow(raw_img)
axes[0].set_title("Raw image")

img = preprocess(raw_img).permute(1, 2, 0)    # <----- Applying preprocessing "manually" on image works
axes[1].imshow(img)
axes[1].set_title("Preprocessed image (manual)")

img = data["train"][0]["img"]                 # <----- Getting image from preprocessed dataset doesn't work (preprocessing is lazy)
axes[2].imshow(img.permute(1, 2, 0))
axes[2].set_title("Preprocessed image (dataset)")

plt.show()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thiba\OneDrive - McGill University\Internship\ECSE301\pytorch_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    img = data["train"][0]["img"]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py", line 2778, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem(key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py", line 2763, in _getitem
    formatted_output = format_table(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\formatting\formatting.py", line 624, in format_table
    return formatter(pa_table, query_type=query_type)
    return self.format_row(pa_table)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\formatting\formatting.py", line 480, in format_row
    formatted_batch = self.format_batch(pa_table)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\datasets\formatting\formatting.py", line 510, in format_batch
    return self.transform(batch)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\_presets.py", line 58, in forward
    img = F.resize(img, self.resize_size, interpolation=self.interpolation, antialias=self.antialias)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py", line 476, in resize
    _, image_height, image_width = get_dimensions(img)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py", line 78, in get_dimensions
    return F_pil.get_dimensions(img)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\_functional_pil.py", line 31, in get_dimensions
    raise TypeError(f"Unexpected type {type(img)}")
TypeError: Unexpected type <class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work:

```
data = raw_data.with_transform(lambda x: {'img': [preprocess(img) for img in x['img']]})
```

Here's an alternative approach which makes use of vectorization:

```
def preprocess_wrapper(data):
    imgs = data['img']
    as_array = imgs.numpy()
    # Note: array must be uint8, not float, or preprocessor will skip
    # step where it normalizes all values from 0-255 to 0-1
    as_tensor = torch.Tensor(as_array).type(torch.uint8)
    # Swap axes: we start with (B, H, W, C) and we need (B, C, H, W)
    permuted = as_tensor.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
    return preprocess(permuted)
data = preprocess_wrapper(raw_data.with_format("tf")['train'])
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't benchmark the two approaches against one another, because it takes [around 32GB](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=224+*+244+*+4+*+3+*+50000+bytes) of memory to hold this many images at such high res.

Comment: It works, but won't that be very slow? Or is that operation still vectorized? I'd like to use GPU acceleration for this

Comment: @ThibautB. See edit for a second attempt.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the second method eagerly preprocesses the data and the allocator says it needs 39 GB of memory which I don't have, so I'll have to stick with the first method.